# CakePHP 1.x end of support date?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is there an official date for when support for CakePHP 1.x branch will end? I keep looking for it but can't find anything about this topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no specific date set for discontinuing support for 1.x branch. 1.3 still has bugfix releases (although months apart) and should continue receiving security updates if needed until further notice.

Comment: Released today version [1.3.21](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/releases/tag/1.3.21) becomes last for 1.3.x branch.